# Parse.com query.limit doesn't work in PFCollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfcollectionviewcell

First, thanks for helping. I am writing an iOs application developed with Swift and i'm using *Parse.com*. In a class named **liste_joueurs**,  there is around 15 rows. However, I just want to retrieve the first four results.

I read the docs and found the **query.limit** property. Unfortunately, when I run my code, in my collection, all the rows from my class appear (the query.limit doesn't work).

Does anyone have a solution ?

```
override func queryForCollection() -> PFQuery {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "liste_joueurs")
    query.limit = 4 // Useless
    query.orderByAscending("nom")
    return query
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject!) -> PFCollectionViewCell? {
    println(object["nom"]?.count)
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("statsCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! StatsViewCell

    // CELL'S TREATMENT  

    return cell
}
```

PS : When I used a constraint like this one :

```
query.whereKey("nom", hasPrefix: "ba")
```

The query "is filtered" and only rows beginning by "ba" appears in my collection...

Comment: update the code for request.

Comment: Make sure you are not setting pageEnabled in that case it will ignore limit.

Comment: Vish. can you explain a bit more please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With only this code I can say if you are using `PFQueryCollectionViewController` than make sure `paginationEnabled = false`, otherwise it will ignore. and if you are using `objectsPerPage` then it will override limit

Comment: Yes !! That's it ! Thanks a lot for your quick answer :)

Comment: don't use objectsPerPage